# Rails post to facebook page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala

I have a rails app that I wish to be able to post to a fb page. I understand Koala is the gem that facilitates this functionality.

I have created a facebook app and have an app_id & app_secret.

Can my facebook app post to a page or does it need to be done by a page admin?

**Application Access Tokens**

> Facebook applications can also get their own access tokens, which can
>   be used to manage realtime updates and perform certain other
>   sessionless activities. To get your app's access token, just run:

```
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(app_id, app_secret)
@oauth.get_app_access_token
```

https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/OAuth

**Edit 1**
From: https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Acting-as-a-Page and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ I understand I will need to obtain an access token and then a page token:

```
@user_graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(user_access_token)
pages = @user_graph.get_connections('me', 'accounts')
page_token = @user_graph.get_page_access_token(page_id)
@page_graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(page_token)
@page_graph.get_object('me') # I'm a page
@page_graph.get_connection('me', 'feed') # the page's wall
@page_graph.put_wall_post('post on page wall') # post as page, requires new publish_pages permission
@page_graph.put_connections(page_id, 'feed', :message => message, :picture => picture_url, :link => link_url)
```

All of the above is self explanatory however I am stuck on one fundamental being how should my rails app obtain a user_access_token. As I want all of the posting to be performed by my rails app "as a page" I would imaging this user_access_token should be set as a constant once in the rails app and not requested every time the rails app needs to post.

The koala home page states this is possible:
**Configuration**

> Most applications will only use one application configuration. Rather
>   than having to provide that value every time, you can configure Koala
>   to use global settings:

```
# In Rails, you could put this in config/initializers/koala.rb
Koala.configure do |config|
  config.access_token = MY_TOKEN
  config.app_access_token = MY_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
  config.app_id = MY_APP_ID
  config.app_secret = MY_APP_SECRET
  # See Koala::Configuration for more options, including details on how to send requests through
  # your own proxy servers.
end
```

https://github.com/arsduo/koala

As I have the app_id and app_secret I am still unsure of how to obtain the access_token and app_access_token required above.

Yes, I am lost.

**Edit 2**
As the user_access_token expires I am confused as to how this can be hard coded into koala.rb?

Comment: No, you can not post as a page using the app access token, that needs a page access token.

Comment: OK, I so the Rails app does all the posting I would need an access token for myself. However as this expires I guess I cannot set it in an initializer.

Comment: Extended page access tokens do not have a default expiry ...

Comment: Thanks Cbroe however I am lost here. Where do I obtain this access token from ? Once obtained I guess I would use it here https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Acting-as-a-Page

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ Plus, the very page you just linked to explains how to acquire one in Koala already ...